# Updating component on mouseMove event very slow

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I've got a div that is having it's location update with onMouseMove events of it's parent. The code below shows how I'm doing it:

```
function Area () {
   const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, })
   const handleMouseMove = event => {
      setMousePos({ 
         x: event.clientX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft,
         y: event.clientY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop,
      })
   }
   const getStyle = () => { top: mousePos.y, left: mousePos.x, };
   return(
      <div className='main-area' onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
         <div style={getStyle()}></div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

There are some css rules that help with the positioning etc. but I think they are irrelevant to the question (let me know if not?).

Anyway, my problem is that I'm getting really high CPU usage (~50% with intel i5-3570k) when moving my mouse inside the 'main-area' div, particularly when there are many other children components involved (not sure if this is because of event bubbling or the way the ReactDOM updates?). This is in the development build of react (I've not tried in production build).

Is this way of updating the position just inherently flawed and slow? Or is there a way to modify it slightly to make it faster?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring:

```
function Area () {
   const [mousePosX, setMousePosX] = useState(0);
   const [mousePosY, setMousePosY] = useState(0);
   const handleMouseMove = event => {
      setMousePosX(event.clientX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft)
      setMousePosY(event.clientY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop)
   }
   return(
      <div className='main-area' onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>
         <div style={{top: mousePosY, left: mousePosX}}></div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Can you check if the performance is better?